# Jquery UI Tabs Direct Links Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a page using the JQuery UI tabs, and my client requires that each tab has a direct link. I solved that with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',function(event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.tab;
    })
});
```

Now when a user clicks on each tab the url appears like: http://url.com/#tablink, that user can then bookmark the URL, but the browser will automatically scroll down to where the #ID is located, which is annoying. I was able to override this when the user is clocking on the tabs by adding the following JQuery code:

```
$(".tab-set ul li a").click(function(e) {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

However I can't find something that works to avoid this when the URL is entered directly in the address bar, rather than clicking a tab. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
        window.onload = scroll(0,0);
```

and

```
        window.onload = scrollTo(0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$(function(){
    $.scrollTo('0px');
    //or
    $.scrollTo('body',0);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but this is just another method for doing the same that I was already doing. The issue I'm having is to get the page to scroll after the tabs have already been loaded, so this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default browsers behavior to scroll to the hash.

You can try this.

```
$(function(){
    if(location.hash && location.hash == "#your-tab-id-name-here") {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ShankarSignoli tried this:`$(function(){
 
    if(location.hash && location.hash == "#tabs-1" || "#tabs-2" || "#tabs-3" || "#tabs-4" || "#tabs-5" ) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 0);
    }

});`

Comment: You can use `||` or condition for tabs and make your code simple.

Comment: @ShankarSignoli But it didn't work, it initially scrolls up, and then gets back down to the #id region...